# Can't find a way to change the row color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have this table:

```
<table class="dataTable" id="repaymentPlan">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> 1 </th>
                        <th> 2 </th>
                        <th> 3 </th>
                        <th>4</th>
                        <th>5</th>
                        <th style="width: 5em;">6(b)</th>
                        <th style="width: 5em;">7</th>
                        <th style="width: 5em;">8</th>                      
                        <th>9</th>
                        <th>-</th>
                        <th>10</th>
                        <th style="width: 5em;">11</th>
                        <th>12</th>
                        <th>13</th>
                        <th>14</th>
                        <th>-</th>
                        <th>15</th>
                        <th>16</th>
                        <th style="width: 5em;">Change font</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: creditCalculationDetails">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="realPlanDate" data-bind="text: realPlanDate"></td>
                        <td class="pro" data-bind="text: pro"></td>
                        <td class="q" data-bind="text: q"></td>
                        <td class="z" data-bind="text: z"></td>
                        <td class="gT" data-bind="text: g"></td>
                        <td class="b" data-bind="text: b" style="width: 5em;"></td>
                        <td class="c" data-bind="text: c" style="width: 5em;"></td>
                        <td class="e" data-bind="text: e" style="width: 5em;"></td>
                        <td class="f" data-bind="text: f"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="assimilationDate" data-bind="text: assimilationDate"></td>
                        <td class="a" data-bind="text: a" style="width: 5em;"></td>
                        <td class="h" data-bind="text: h"></td>
                        <td class="i" data-bind="text: i"></td>
                        <td class="eT" data-bind="text: eT"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="mDays" data-bind="text: mDays" style="width: 5em;"></td>
                        <td class="nDays" data-bind="text: nDays" style="width: 5em;"></td>

                        <td class="changeFont" data-bind="text: changeFont" style="width: 5em;"></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

where `<td class="realPlanDate" data-bind="text: realPlanDate"></td>` keeps a date String and `<td class="changeFont" data-bind="text: changeFont" style="width: 5em;"></td>` returns `1` when the `realPlanDate` of the previous row is the same as the date of the current row and `0` when it's not the same.

Now it looks like this:
![image][1]

I'm achieveing it in my view model with the code below:

```
changeFont = function(){
                           var rowId = 0;
                           var prevRowId = 0;
                           var prevChangeFont = null;
                           var flag = false;

                              $("tbody").find("tr").each(function() {   
                                  console.log("test: " + rowId);
                                 console.log("prevTest: " + prevRowId);
                                    var paymentDate = $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').text();
                                    var pro = $(this).find('td.pro').text();
                                    var q = $(this).prev().find('td.q').text();
                                    var z = $(this).find('td.z').text(); 
                                    var gT =   $(this).find('td.gT').text(); 
                                    var b = $(this).find('td.b').text(); 
                                    var c = $(this).prev().find('td.c').text();
                                    var e = $(this).find('td.e').text();
                                    var f = $(this).find('td.f').text();
                                    var assimilationDate = $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').text();
                                    var a = $(this).find('td.a').text();
                                    var h = $(this).find('td.h').text();
                                    var i = $(this).find('td.i').text();
                                    var eT = $(this).find('td.eT').text();
                                    var mDays = $(this).find('td.mDays').text();
                                    var nDays = $(this).find('td.nDays').text();
                                    var changeFont = $(this).find('td.changeFont').text();


                                   if(rowId == 0){
                                        $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                        $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                    }
                                    if(rowId == 1){
                                        $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                        $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                    }

                                    prevRowId = rowId;
                                    if(rowId == 0){
                                        rowId = 1;
                                    }else{
                                        rowId = 0;
                                    }
                                    prevChangeFont = changeFont;
                              });
                           };
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace the row color with the color of the `previous` row, when `changeFont == 1`, but I can't find a way.

I have tried this(really nooby), but it doesn't work:

```
               changeFont = function(){
                   var rowId = 0;
                   var prevRowId = 0;
                   var prevChangeFont = null;
                   var flag = false;

                      $("tbody").find("tr").each(function() {   
                          console.log("test: " + rowId);
                         console.log("prevTest: " + prevRowId);
                            var paymentDate = $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').text();
                            var pro = $(this).find('td.pro').text();
                            var q = $(this).prev().find('td.q').text();
                            var z = $(this).find('td.z').text(); 
                            var gT =   $(this).find('td.gT').text(); 
                            var b = $(this).find('td.b').text(); 
                            var c = $(this).prev().find('td.c').text();
                            var e = $(this).find('td.e').text();
                            var f = $(this).find('td.f').text();
                            var assimilationDate = $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').text();
                            var a = $(this).find('td.a').text();
                            var h = $(this).find('td.h').text();
                            var i = $(this).find('td.i').text();
                            var eT = $(this).find('td.eT').text();
                            var mDays = $(this).find('td.mDays').text();
                            var nDays = $(this).find('td.nDays').text();
                            var changeFont = $(this).find('td.changeFont').text();


                           if(rowId == 0){
                                $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                            }
                            if(rowId == 1){
                                $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                            }
                            if(rowId == 0 && prevRowId == 1 && changeFont == 1 && prevChangeFont == 1){
                                $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                flag = true;
                            }
                           if(rowId == 0 && prevRowId == 1 && changeFont == 1 && prevChangeFont == 0){
                                $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                flag = true;
                            }
                            if(rowId == 1 && prevRowId == 0 && changeFont == 1 && prevChangeFont == 1){
                                $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                flag = true;
                            }
                           if(rowId == 1 && prevRowId == 0 && changeFont == 1 && prevChangeFont == 0){
                                $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                flag = true;
                            }
                           if(rowId == 1 && prevRowId == 0 && flag){
                              $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                           }
                          if(rowId == 0 && prevRowId == 1 && flag){
                             $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#819FF7');
                           }
                         if(rowId == 1 && prevRowId == 0 && flag){
                             $(this).find('td.realPlanDate').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.pro').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.q').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.z').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.gT').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.b').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.c').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.e').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.f').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.assimilationDate').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.a').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.h').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.i').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.eT').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.mDays').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.nDays').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                                $(this).find('td.changeFont').css('backgroundColor', '#CED8F6');
                           }

                            prevRowId = rowId;
                            if(rowId == 0){
                                rowId = 1;
                            }else{
                                rowId = 0;
                            }
                            prevChangeFont = changeFont;
                      });
                   };
```

Please, give me a clue on the issue, I'm lost and really can't think of a logic way to achieve what I want.

Comment: first of all, you are setting every td by hand with specific color. You can have your <tr> with 2 classes odd / even and set a css rule for al tr.odd td {} and tr.even td {} . As for changing the color later on you can use jQuery(this).parent('tr').find(td).css..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily maintain this with [css only solution](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html):

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: yes, but when `changeFont == 1` will I be able to get the color of the preious row?

Comment: use on click $('tr:nth-child(even)'){background: #FFF} reverting again.